Trying to enable / disable Azure logic app at specific time period
I am currently building a logic app that will turn off a VM during the months of January through March and May through November. The rest of the time, the VM will be turned on. This part of the logic app is working as intended.
A second logic app is requested to turn the VM (during the periods it is supposed to be on) off during the nights and on at the start of the day.
Does anybody know how to trigger the second logic app to enable during the "on season"? I obviously don't want the second logic app to turn on the VM during the periods it is supposed to be turned off.
I would love to hear from you!
My idea is to run:
@or(and(greaterOrEquals(utcNow('MMdd'), '0401', lessOrEquals(utcNow('MMdd'), '0501')(and(greaterOrEquals(utcNow('MMdd'), '1201', lessOrEquals(utcNow('MMdd'), '0101')')
through the occurrence setting, but I have no idea if this will be enough / correct

Recently we had a similar situation of starting and stopping VM's. We used the Azute Automation Service that resolved our needs. The Azure Automation services provides with 2 Logic App that can start and stop VM's. You can also customize these to logic App to your reqiremen. It seems that you need to start/stop of the VM's to work on April and December alone. What I would suggest is to clone the start Logic App created by the Automation Service and then add additional logic to it.
The details of the Azure Automation Sevice MSDN reference as as below

Start/Stop VMs v2 overview
Deploy Start/Stop VMs v2 to an Azure subscription

A simple and straight forward way will be use the swicth case to check the utcNow('MM') [returns month number as 01, 02, 03 ...12) and perform the start / stop of the VM's. Please see if this helps
Default Logic Start App

Modified Logic App with Month Condition

If condition with OR filter for month


Thanks for the help! In the end I decided to build a switch that checked for the months, followed by a "less or greater than" that checked the specific day of the month. This should allow me to automatically turn the VM on during the dates I know I have to turn it on and not when the VM is supposed to be dormant.

Your code wouldn't work because a value cannot be greater than '1201' and less than '0101' at the same time.
Why don't you just check the months without checking the dates? Something like this:
@contains(createArray('04', '12'), utcNow('MM'))

You can't use this check in the Recurrence trigger, but you can have a Condition action immediately after.

You are absolutely correct, that was a massive oversight on my part!
